# Remove session in url - Laravel

Tags: php, session, laravel, laravel-4

I would like to remove the laravel_session in the url:

The first time when I come on the site, it appears but when I click on an another link, it disappears.

I would like to remove it when I just come on the site.
I have something like this: *index?laravel_session=9bujan8gjmbtfb1qig6rju23c5*

I try to change the session drive of Laravel. I try to put it on "array",but it removes the laravel_session however sessions are not persisted.

Currently, I use 'cookie'.

Answer (score 1):

This isn't a laravel issue, this is a php config issue. See this page http://www.php.net/manual/en/session.idpassing.php

You can change it by adding the following line to your bootstrap code

```
ini_set('session.use_trans_sid', false);
```

**or** by editing .htaccess and adding the following line to the top of the file

```
php_value session.use_trans_sid false
```

**or** by editing php.ini if you are able

All in all if you can't edit the php.ini file the .htaccess method is cleaner.